# Not able to upload HTML page using ESP8266

Tags: c, embedded, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to display Temperature and Humidity reading of [SHT31](https://store.ncd.io/product/sht31-humidity-and-temperature-sensor-%C2%B12rh-%C2%B10-3c-i2c-mini-module/) sensor on the HTML page,
but whenever I am trying to write the IP in the web browser and searching, the Error - "This site can not be reached" has been displayed.

I am working on code(mentioned below) to connect and Interfacing I2C module of Temperature sensor with [Adafruit Huzzah ESP8266](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2471) using Library "ESP8266WiFi.h", "Wire.h"

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// SHT31 I2C address is 0x44(68)
#define Addr 0x44
// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "SSID";
const char* password = "Password";
float Ctemp,Ftemp,humid;

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

void setup() 
{
  Wire.begin(2,14);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  temptask();
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) 
  {                             // If a new client connects,

    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
         if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();


            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
            client.println("<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0\">");
            client.println("<body style= \"background-color:#EDEEF2\">");
            client.println("<h1 style= \"color:blue\">Temperature and Humidity</h1>");
            client.println( "<h3 style= \"font-family:verdana; color:blue\">Temperature in Celcius:</h3>");
            client.println("<p style=\"font-size:160%; font-family:Lucida Console\">"+String(Ctemp,1)+"</p>");
            client.println("<h3 style= \"font-family:verdana; color:blue\">Temperature in Fahrenheit:</h3>");
            client.println("<p style=\"font-size:160%; font-family:Lucida Console\">"+String(Ftemp,1)+"</p>");
            client.println("<h3 style= \"font-family:verdana; color:blue\">Humidity:</h3>");
            client.println("<p style=\"font-size:160%; font-family:Lucida Console\">"+String(humid,1)+"</p>");
            client.println("</body>");
            client.println("</html>");
            break;
          } 
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
}



void temptask(){
 unsigned int data[6];

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Send 16-bit command byte
  Wire.write(0x2C);
  Wire.write(0x06);
  // Stop I2C transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(300);

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Stop I2C Transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Request 6 bytes of data
  Wire.requestFrom(Addr, 6);

  // Read 6 bytes of data
  // temp msb, temp lsb, temp crc, hum msb, hum lsb, hum crc
  if (Wire.available() == 6)
  {
    data[0] = Wire.read();
    data[1] = Wire.read();
    data[2] = Wire.read();
    data[3] = Wire.read();
    data[4] = Wire.read();
    data[5] = Wire.read();
  }
  // Convert the data
  int temp = (data[0] * 256) + data[1];
  float cTemp = -45.0 + (175.0 * temp / 65535.0);
  float fTemp = (cTemp * 1.8) + 32.0;
  float humidity = (100.0 * ((data[3] * 256.0) + data[4])) / 65535.0;  
  Ctemp = cTemp;
  Ftemp = fTemp;
  humidity = humid;

   Serial.print("Temperature in C:\t");
   Serial.println(String(cTemp,1));
   Serial.print("Temperature in F:\t");
   Serial.println(String(fTemp,1));
   Serial.print("Humidity:\t ");
   Serial.println(String(humidity,1));
 }
```

Any advice about what causing this issue will very grateful.

Comment: Your title says "problem with displaying temperature" But the body indicates that you are not even able to load any page at all. You should update your question title or body to match. If your problem is the latter, you could remove all the temperature stuff and focus on the basic mechanisms first.

Comment: Can you write what your computer can read on the serial link?

Comment: I am able to connect with wifi on the serial monitor as well as able to see the readings on it as mentioned:
{
.......
WiFi connected.
IP address: 
192.168.1.35
Temperature in C: 26.1
Temperature in F: 78.9
Humidity:  0.0
}
But not able to upload the HTML page and the error is showing while connecting to the default IP mentioned in the serial monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code and is working fine now kindly take a look.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

// SHT31 I2C address is 0x44(68)
#define Addr 0x44

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "DcubeAirtel";
const char* password = "D@Airtel190";
float Ctemp,Ftemp,humid;

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

void setup() 
{
  Wire.begin(2,14);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
 }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  temptask();
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) 
   {                             // If a new client connects,

    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data 
     from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the 
     client,
       String c = client.readStringUntil('\r');             // read a byte, then
       Serial.println(c);
     }                    // print it out the serial monitor
       // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
       // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
        // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
        // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        client.println("Content-type:text/html");
        client.println("Connection: close");
        client.println();

          String PAGE2 = 
 "<!DOCTYPE html>"
 "<html>"
 "<head>"
 "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">"
 "<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0\">"
 "<title> My first HTML page</title>"
 "</head>"
 "<body style= \"background-color:#EDEEF2\">"
 "<h1 style= \"color:blue\">Temperature and Humidity</h1>"
 "<h3 style= \"font-family:verdana; color:blue\">Temperature in Celcius:</h3>"
 "<p style=\"font-size:160%; font-family:Lucida Console\">"+String(Ctemp,1)+
 "</p>"
 "<h3 style= \"font-family:verdana; color:blue\">Temperature in Fahrenheit:</h3>"
 "<p style=\"font-size:160%; font-family:Lucida Console\">"+String(Ftemp,1)+
 "</p>"
 "<h3 style= \"font-family:verdana; color:blue\">Humidity:</h3>"
 "<p style=\"font-size:160%; font-family:Lucida Console\">"+String(humid,1)+
 "</p>"
 "</body>"
 "</html>";
        // Display the HTML web page
        client.println(PAGE2);

      } 
}
// Clear the header variable

// Close the connection
client.stop();
Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
Serial.println("");
 }
void temptask(){
  unsigned int data[6];

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Send 16-bit command byte
  Wire.write(0x2C);
  Wire.write(0x06);
  // Stop I2C transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(300);

  // Start I2C Transmission
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr);
  // Stop I2C Transmission
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Request 6 bytes of data
  Wire.requestFrom(Addr, 6);

 // Read 6 bytes of data
 // temp msb, temp lsb, temp crc, hum msb, hum lsb, hum crc
 if (Wire.available() == 6)
 {
   data[0] = Wire.read();
   data[1] = Wire.read();
   data[2] = Wire.read();
   data[3] = Wire.read();
   data[4] = Wire.read();
   data[5] = Wire.read();
  }
  // Convert the data
  int temp = (data[0] * 256) + data[1];
  float cTemp = -45.0 + (175.0 * temp / 65535.0);
  float fTemp = (cTemp * 1.8) + 32.0;
  float humidity = (100.0 * ((data[3] * 256.0) + data[4])) / 65535.0;  
  Ctemp = cTemp;
  Ftemp = fTemp;
  humidity = humid;

  Serial.print("Temperature in C:\t");
  Serial.println(String(cTemp,1));
  Serial.print("Temperature in F:\t");
  Serial.println(String(fTemp,1));
  Serial.print("Humidity:\t ");
  Serial.println(String(humidity,1));
}
```

This works as follows:

1. First read the char sent by server till next line
2. Now flush the server
3. Now write your content to the server.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply but the Sensor data is printing in Loop while reading it in HTML page can you tell where is the problem?

Comment: you need to break the loop, just put the break statement at the end of while(client.connected()); loop

Comment: Hey Vaibhav, thanks for your support it is working completely fine now